# Puppet won't detect augeas

Tags: puppet, debian-wheezy

*Puppet version: 3.1.1*

When attempting to use [activemq](https://github.com/maestrodev/puppet-activemq) module:

```
package {'openjdk-6-jre-headless':
    ensure => present,
}
class {'activemq':
    version => '5.8.0',
    user    => 'activemq',
    group   => 'activemq',
    home    => '/opt',
    console => true,
}
# following block causes issues with augeas
class { 'activemq::stomp':
    port => 61613,
}
```

I receive this error, running from node:

```
# puppet agent --test
Info: Retrieving plugin
Info: Loading facts in /var/lib/puppet/lib/facter/pe_version.rb
Info: Loading facts in /var/lib/puppet/lib/facter/root_home.rb
Info: Loading facts in /var/lib/puppet/lib/facter/puppet_vardir.rb
Info: Caching catalog for xxx
Info: Applying configuration version '1368621971'
Notice: /Stage[main]/Activemq/Service[activemq]: Dependency Augeas[activemq-stomp] has failures: true
Warning: /Stage[main]/Activemq/Service[activemq]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
Error: Could not find a suitable provider for augeas
Notice: Finished catalog run in 0.41 seconds
```

If I run it with `--debug`, this is the output (grepped for augeas, for clarity):

```
# puppet agent --test --debug|grep augeas -i
Debug: Failed to load library 'augeas' for feature 'augeas'
Debug: Failed to load library 'augeas' for feature 'augeas'
Debug: Puppet::Type::Augeas::ProviderAugeas: feature augeas is missing
Debug: Failed to load library 'augeas' for feature 'augeas'
Debug: Puppet::Type::Augeas::ProviderAugeas: feature augeas is missing
Debug: /Stage[main]/Activemq::Stomp/Augeas[activemq-stomp]/require: requires File[/opt/activemq]
Debug: /Stage[main]/Activemq::Stomp/Augeas[activemq-stomp]/notify: subscribes to Service[activemq]
Debug: Failed to load library 'augeas' for feature 'augeas'
Debug: Puppet::Type::Augeas::ProviderAugeas: feature augeas is missing
Debug: Failed to load library 'augeas' for feature 'augeas'
Debug: Puppet::Type::Augeas::ProviderAugeas: feature augeas is missing
Notice: /Stage[main]/Activemq/Service[activemq]: Dependency Augeas[activemq-stomp] has failures: true
Warning: /Stage[main]/Activemq/Service[activemq]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
Error: Could not find a suitable provider for augeas
```

Update 1: Augeas appears to be installed correctly:

```
# dpkg -l | grep augeas
ii  augeas-lenses            0.10.0-1     all
ii  augeas-tools             0.10.0-1     amd64
ii  libaugeas-ruby1.8        0.4.1-1.1    amd64
ii  libaugeas0               0.10.0-1     amd64
```

Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: Have you installed the required packages? `apt-cache search augeas` and `dpkg -l | grep augeas`

Comment: @dawud yes, updated question with relevant information.

Comment: You are apparently using the puppetlabs' repo and you are missing `libaugeas-ruby1.9.1`, install it and check if that makes a difference.

Comment: it worked! write this as an answer, if you wish to receive rep. now, could someone explain to me why wrong version of libaugeas-ruby was installed? can I make sure it gets installed by some means, other than forcing clients to install said `package`?

Comment: What's also interesting is that `ruby` metapackage is at version `1.9.3`, so in my opinion, it should default to installing 1.9.x ruby packages, no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the information reported by the one of the [packages](http://apt.puppetlabs.com/pool/wheezy/main/p/puppet/puppet-common_3.1.1-1puppetlabs1_all.deb), it depends of any of `libaugeas-ruby1.{8,9}`

```
# dpkg --info puppet-common_3.1.1-1puppetlabs1_all.deb
 Package: puppet-common
 Source: puppet
 Version: 3.1.1-1puppetlabs1
 Architecture: all
 Maintainer: Puppet Labs 
 Installed-Size: 3592
 Depends: ruby | ruby-interpreter, libxmlrpc-ruby, libopenssl-ruby, libshadow-ruby1.8 | ruby-shadow, libaugeas-ruby1.8 | libaugeas-ruby1.9, adduser, lsb-base, sysv-rc (>= 2.86) | file-rc, hiera (>= 1.0.0), facter (>= 1.6.12)
 Homepage: http://projects.puppetlabs.com/projects/puppet
```

So I would guess that you are setting ruby 1.9 to be the default. This can be checked using:

```
# update-alternatives --display ruby
ruby - auto mode
  link currently points to /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1
/usr/bin/ruby1.8 - priority 50
  slave erb: /usr/bin/erb1.8
  slave erb.1.gz: /usr/share/man/man1/erb1.8.1.gz
  slave irb: /usr/bin/irb1.8
  slave irb.1.gz: /usr/share/man/man1/irb1.8.1.gz
  slave rdoc: /usr/bin/rdoc1.8
  slave rdoc.1.gz: /usr/share/man/man1/rdoc1.8.1.gz
  slave ri: /usr/bin/ri1.8
  slave ri.1.gz: /usr/share/man/man1/ri1.8.1.gz
  slave ruby.1.gz: /usr/share/man/man1/ruby1.8.1.gz
  slave testrb: /usr/bin/testrb1.8
  slave testrb.1.gz: /usr/share/man/man1/testrb1.8.1.gz
/usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 - priority 51
  slave erb: /usr/bin/erb1.9.1
  slave erb.1.gz: /usr/share/man/man1/erb1.9.1.1.gz
  slave irb: /usr/bin/irb1.9.1
  slave irb.1.gz: /usr/share/man/man1/irb1.9.1.1.gz
  slave rdoc: /usr/bin/rdoc1.9.1
  slave rdoc.1.gz: /usr/share/man/man1/rdoc1.9.1.1.gz
  slave ri: /usr/bin/ri1.9.1
  slave ri.1.gz: /usr/share/man/man1/ri1.9.1.1.gz
  slave ruby.1.gz: /usr/share/man/man1/ruby1.9.1.1.gz
  slave testrb: /usr/bin/testrb1.9.1
  slave testrb.1.gz: /usr/share/man/man1/testrb1.9.1.1.gz
Current 'best' version is '/usr/bin/ruby1.9.1'.
```

Comment: Two answers in one. Nice.

Comment: To answer my own sub-question from above, I think the confusion appeared because I did an upgrade from squeeze to wheezy, and libaugeas-ruby package was already installed, which means there was no need to install another version of same package, thus creating a problem I have been experiencing.

Comment: As it is a third party package the one that triggers the dependency error, I would not know who to report the error to, though. Maybe PuppetLabs.